# How to set attributes to a dynamically created jquery select2?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2

I'm creating a jquery select2 (a jQuery based replacement for select boxes) and dynamically loading the options through `$.post`.

I want to add dynamic data.  Attributes to each of the options but I can't figure it out how.

This is what I have:

```
$("#pa_billSchedule").select2({
    data: myResults
}).select2('val', []);
```

Where `myResults` is the data returned from the `$.post` on the standard format: `(id: "", text: "")`

Comment: What will you do with those `data-` attributes? I'm asking because maybe you could add those attributes directly into the data JSON (and then you'll have something like `{id: '', text: '', dataCustom: ''}`

Comment: Hi milz thanks for replying. That's what I want to do, I added a dataCustom to the JSON and I wanted to apply to the option. I want that when someone selects the option it will use that information to define behavior in another and calculate it on another field of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the `$.change()` event. Check this [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/4f1syu2a/):

```
<input type="hidden" name="pa_billSchedule" id="pa_billSchedule" />
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pa_billSchedule").select2({
       // this is for testing purposes. You should use `myResults`
       data: [
        {id: 1, text: 'first', customData: 'red'},
        {id: 2, text: 'second', customData: 'green'},
        {id: 3, text: 'third', customData: 'blue'}
       ]
    }).select2('val', [])
    .on('change', function() {
        // and this is where you get the custom attribute
        if ($(this).select2('data').customData == 'red') {
            alert('the first option was selected');
            // do what you need
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! I didn't know that the variable would persist after you loaded so I was trying to make it work on the load!! Thanks milz that was perfect!

Comment: just one thing I notice on the JsFiddle, it doesn't check when it load the select2, it will say "The first option was selected" only if you select another option and then go back and select it again. How can we make it verify including when it's loaded? Thank you again!

Comment: If you want to automatically select the first option, you must set the `.select('val', 1)`. Besides this, in order for the code to run, you need to trigger the `change` event after initialize the select2. Please visit [**this JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/4f1syu2a/1/) where I've made those changes. If this answer is useful to you, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi milz! You really help me out and explained very clearly! Thanks again

Comment: One more question, just wonder if you don't know the id of the first one, if it's dynamically pull from the database, how can you set it?

Comment: Instead of hardcoding `.select2('val', 1)`, you should use `.select2('val', myResults[0].id)`. Here's the [**updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/4f1syu2a/2/)